# ImageView заменит все

Tags: android, android-imageview

Разобрал оф. клиент ВК для андроид и ради интереса зашёл в разметку плеера. Они использовали `ImageView` для всех кнопок. Зачем так делать? Ведь есть же `ImageButton`, `ToggleButton`.

Это лень кастомизацию делать?

Comment: Сам я клиентом ВК не пользовался, но возможно их контролам не нужна визуализация событий касания или вообще этот "кнопочный" фон, тогда `ImageView` использовать уместнее, чем `ImageButton`, меньше движений

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По своему определению:

```
public class ImageButton extends ImageView {...}
```

По сути `ImageButton` отличается от `ImageView` только наличием своего предопределенного стиля, который в некоторых своих ипостасях как бы эмулирует эффект нажатия. Это не всем нравится, особенно сейчас в эпоху, когда плоский дизайн стал трендом.

Ну и есть еще одно обстоятельство: когда ты берешь класс родитель, то получаешь чуточку больше контроля над поведением объекта (в обмен на количество кода, естественно). Некоторым прогерам кажется, что это айс.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такой термин как `ПРИ́ХОТЬ` который имеет значение: Капризное желание, причуда.

Программисты они часто пишут кашу место маленького кода. Часто сталкивался с таким, они сильно закручивают все и так далее... Видел разметку где сделали `TextView` невидимым и хранили пароли в нем ))))))))) Это просто Ужас на таких вещах не зацикливайтесь не стоит внимания.